# How to get the specific number wrote in the file using assertEquals

Tags: file, loading

This is the DistanceMeasurement class of the ArrayList.

```
public abstract class DistanceMeasurement {

/**
 * The distance reported by this DistanceMeasurement.
 * 
 * @return the distance
 */
public abstract int getDistance();
```

This is the class the test class will be pulling from.

```
private ArrayList<DistanceMeasurement> measurements;

/**
 * Creates a new controller.
 */
public DistancesFileController() {
    this.measurements = new ArrayList<DistanceMeasurement>();
}

/**
 * Gets the distance measurements
 * 
 * @return the distance measurements.
 */
public DistanceMeasurement[] getMeasurements() {
    return this.measurements.toArray(new DistanceMeasurement[0]);
}
/**
 * loads contents from a file
 * 
 * @param file the file of the we are loading from
 * @throws FileNotFoundException file is not found 
 */
public void loadFrom(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    this.measurements.clear();
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        String numbers = parts[0];
        SimpleDistanceMeasurement measurement = new SimpleDistanceMeasurement(Integer.parseInt(numbers));
        this.measurements.add(measurement);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

This is the test class that i am trying to write the assertEquals in to see if the right number was added to the file.

```
/**
 * Creates new temporary folder
 */
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
private DistancesFileController controller;
private  File saveFile;
/**
 * Called before all tests in this suite.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 *             n/a
 */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {


    this.controller = new DistancesFileController();
    this.saveFile = this.folder.newFile();      
} 
/**
 * Loads an empty file 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException  throws found not found exception
 */
@Test
public void whenLoadingEmptyFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(this.saveFile);
    writer.close();
    this.controller.loadFrom(this.saveFile);
    assertEquals(0, this.controller.getMeasurements().length);
}
/**
 * Loads an file with one thing inside 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException  throws found not found exception
 */
@Test
public void whenLoadingSingleLineFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(this.saveFile);
    writer.println(56);
    writer.close();
    this.controller.loadFrom(this.saveFile);
    //Asserted to see if the file had one thing inside
    assertEquals(1, this.controller.getMeasurements().length);
   //Trying to put an assertEquals here to get the number 57 from the list
}
```

Comment: Make the question easier to answer by including your code as text and not as an image!

Comment: Add your code by edit your question and remove the images.